# Gson fails to convert String value to List, Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I thought that Im strong enough to *play* with Gson but I found some problem.

I have String that I need to convert to Object. The String is generated from some xml.

Here is example of **1st one**:

```
{
"ClientData": {
    "pixelList": {
        "pixel": [{
            "b": 22,
            "a": 1234
        },
        {
            "b": 33,
            "a": 34344
        }]
    }
}
}
```

Seems simple, right?

So I created followed classes and succeeded to convert above mentioned String to Java Object.

```
public class ClientDataRoot {
   @SerializedName("ClientData") ClientData clientData = null;  
}

public class ClientData {   
   PixelList pixelList = null;      
}

public class PixelList {
   List<Pixel> pixel = null;
}

public class Pixel {    
   private String a = "";
   private String b = "";
```

}

From 1st example you can see that `pixelList` has 2 objects: `pixel`.

But what happens if you get `pixelList` with one `pixel`:

**2nd one**:

```
{
"ClientData": {
    "pixelList": {
        "pixel": {
            "b": 22,
            "a": 1234
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here I get the error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer
com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@d1918a failed to deserialize
json object {"b":22,"a":1234} given the type java.util.List<com.wefi.uxt.Pixel>
```

My code is simple:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
....
Gson gson = new Gson();
ClientDataRoot clientDataRoot1 = 
gson.fromJson(xmlJSONObj.toString(), ClientDataRoot.class);
```

I use `gson-1.7.1.jar`

BTW  if I change class `PixelList` from

```
 public class PixelList {
   List<Pixel> pixel = null;
 }
```

to:

```
 public class PixelList {
    Pixel  pixel = null;
 }
```

It works, but I need it as List

Thank you,

**How to Fix it:**

As guys say when I try to convert XML to JSON, the plugin converts `pixel` to `JSONObjext` instead `JSONArray`.

Here is a code I fixed my problem:

```
  // responseBody is XML String
  JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(responseBody);

            JSONObject cd = (JSONObject) xmlJSONObj.get("ClientData");
            JSONObject pl = (JSONObject) cd.get("pixelList");
            Object p = pl.get("pixel");

            if (p instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
                arr.put(p);

                pl.remove("pixel");
                pl.put("pixel", arr);
            }
```

Thanks to PeterMmm and R.J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because either the `JSON` returning third party is returning a wrong `JSON`, or if you're generating the `JSON` yourself, you're doing it wrongly. A **single element** in `pixelList` should have a `JSON` that would look like this:-

```
{
    "clientData": {
        "pixelList": {
            "pixel": [
                {
                    "a": "22",
                    "b": "1234"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Either the JSON needs to be corrected or else, you can do something like this. Have 2 objects, 1 of the `type1`(one which parses a list) and the other of `type2`(one which parses a single element json).

Now parse the json with `type1` class and keep it in a `try-catch`. If you get this `Exception`, `catch` it and parse it with the `type2` class. This seems to be the only workaround, if you can't get the `JSON` response fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I found solution (didnt mention in my question, posted in the bottom of question)

Answer (score 2):

Sould'nt this be in this form ? Pixel with 1 element:

```
{
"ClientData": {
    "pixelList":{
        "pixel": [{
            "b": 22,
            "a": 1234
        }]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are right, but I got this text file from XML and can't change GSON content. Or only parse it

Comment: Then declare a 2nd class to cover this case and catch the Exception.

Comment: Thanks, I found solution (didnt mention in my question, posted in the bottom of question)